# How to hide/collapse div when click on outside by using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have made simple Javascript function for show and hide but unable to trigger outside click hide function.

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showhide()" class="btn" >click </a>

<div id="myID">
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .btn{

    color:red;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;


}

#test{
    display:none;
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:10px
}
```

**Javascript**

```
    function showhide(){
       var div = document.getElementById("test");
            if (div.style.display !== "none") {
                div.style.display = "none";
            }
        else {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }
}
```

Please check this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rupesx26/eg991yg6/1/).

No jQuery please.
Thanks

Comment: As in what you want to do?..Click on outside u mean body??

Comment: Have you googled it ? For example  look here for the road to your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893144/javascript-detect-click-event-outside-of-div

Comment: when you click on outside of "hello world" it should be hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this naively by handling global click events, and help yourself by maintaining state.

In the example below, clicks within the element never reach the `document`, but those outside do via propagation. Clicking the button always toggles the display. Keep in mind, clicking on any element, or propagating to any element, that stops propagation of the `click` event to the `document` will cause this to not respond properly.

```js
var toggle = (function () {
  var visible = false,
      ele = document.getElementById('test'),
      btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
  
  function flip () {
    var display = ele.style.display;
    
    ele.style.display = (display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
    visible = !visible;
  }
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', flip);
  
  ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (visible && e.target !== btn) flip();
  });
  
  ele.style.display = 'none';
  
  return flip;
}());
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  width: 180px;
}

#test {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  line-height: 96px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click!</button>

<div id="test">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Documentation:

- [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`Document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`Event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: from your code, I have update my code but whenever define global variable for "test" id its showing "null" value http://jsfiddle.net/rupesx26/eg991yg6/11/ (working) http://jsfiddle.net/rupesx26/eg991yg6/12/ (Null value)

Answer (score 0):

you can use two functions such as onclick and onfocusout in javscript

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="showhide()" onfocusout = "focusout()"  class="btn"> click </a>

<div id="test">
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>

<script>
    function showhide(){
           var div = document.getElementById("test");
            div.style.display = "block";
    }

    function focusout(){
        var div = document.getElementById("test");
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```