# Reload the page if i click on outside the multiple dropdown box using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a small query, I have a multiple dropdown box in my form. after selecting multiple value, if I click on outside the multiple drop down box page should reload. How can I make it happen using javascript. I have used `"onmouseout(reload.form)"` option but it is not working. Please help me on this.

Thanks
Ranjith

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you might need click event rather mouseout(which is not on click but when mouse loses the focus).

For more details about click outside the element refer the below link

[Javascript Detect Click event outside of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893144/javascript-detect-click-event-outside-of-div)

So once you capture the click out event, you can just trigger the page load using

> > window.location.reload(true) or window.location.reload(false)
> >
> > true or false depends on you need to load from cache or server.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I go through the link you provided above, but my query is If I click anywhere in the page, that page should reload with parameters. Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should really connect to the change() signal on the select box instead. By depending on the mouse event, you will prevent people form using your form with the keyboard only, for instance. `onmouseout` will also not work on mobile devices