# How can i add event listener in Vue customized directive?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events

I'm using Vue2.x and I want to add a event listener by using customising directives, however in vue1.x I can use the following code snippet:

```
Vue.directive('demo',{
  bind () {
    let self  = this
    this.event = function (event) {
      self.vm.$emit(self.expression, event)
    }
    this.el.addEventListener('click', this.stopProp)
    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.event)
  }
})
```

but in vue2.x, I found that 'this' is always undefined, and I cannot figure out how to get the vm (Vue Instance) object. I've tried all the passed parameter list on [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).

Does anyone know how to get access to the vm object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few differences, and you can see a full, working example of your snippet (though tweaked a little) at [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBdBrG?editors=1011), but I'll elaborate here:

Your references to `this` are invalid because in the directive's context `this` refers to the `window`. Instead of these references:

```
this.event = ...
// ...
self.vm.$emit()
// ...
self.expression
```

you should be consuming the three arguments passed to `bind()`:

1. `el` - the DOM element
2. `binding` - binding object for the directive's metadata, including `expression`
3. `vnode` - VNode object - its `context` property is the Vue instance

With those in hand those three lines above would then correspond with:

```
el.event = ...
// ...
vnode.context.$emit()
// ..
binding.expression
```

Finally, a side note: your event listeners would cause nothing to happen because your click on the element triggers a `stopProp` function (that is excluded from your snippet), which presumably calls `stopPropagation()` but then you attempt to catch the propagated event on the `body`.

Comment: I just try to add click-outside event to a div.Like this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170425/detect-click-outside-element](Detect click outside element).But I found that the $emit callback doesn't work.Anyway I found the [vue-clickaway](https://github.com/simplesmiler/vue-clickaway) project.Thanks a lot.