# Close all popups when the user click to open a new one

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a Vue 2.3.3 user and I have a system of popup submenus.

HeaderSubmenu is the name of the component which display a button to open/close the submenu, and the submenu when it's open.

Here's the template of the component :

```
<template>
  <li class="header-submenu">
    <!-- élément du header servant à ouvrir le sous-menu -->
    <header-link v-bind="$props" :href="to ? false : '#'" @click.native.stop="toggle">
      <slot name="item"></slot>
    </header-link>
    <!-- sous-menu -->
    <ul class="submenu-list" :class="{'open': open, 'animated': animated}" @animationend="displaynone()" v-clickout="hide">
      <slot></slot>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>
```

The component use a mixin which contains the `toggle()` and `hide()` methods. These two methods put the right value in `open` and `animated` data variables.
Then, CSS styling applies the right display property and animations.
(When I coded that I didn't know about built-in  component, I'll rework this later.)

Mixin used for toggle CSS classes :

```
export default {
  data () { return {
    open: false,
    animated: false
  };},

  methods:{
    toggle(e){
      this.animated = true;
      this.open = !this.open;
    },
    displaynone(e){
      if(!this.open) this.animated = false;
    },
    show(e){
      if(!this.open){
        this.animated = true;
        this.open = true;
      }
    },
    hide(e){
      if(this.open){
        this.animated = true;
        this.open = false;
      }
    },
  }
}
```

v-clickout is a custom directive who call the method `hide()` when the user clicks somewhere it isn't on the element (here it's the ).
So, I had to put the `stop` modifier on the button click event to prevent the  popup to be closed immediately after being opened.

Directive clickout :

```
export default {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.event = function (event) {
      // here I check that click was outside the el and his childrens
      if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
        // and if it did, call method provided in attribute value
        vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
      }
    };
    document.body.addEventListener('click', el.event)
  },
  unbind(el) {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.event)
  },
};
```

The problem is that now, I can't have two (or more) of these popup menus on the same page :
if I open a first popup menu, and then open a second one, because of the `stop` modifier, the first popup menu doesn't close. I'd wanted to have one popup menu open at a time. If we open a new one, the popup menus already open would close.

How can I achieve this ?
Do I have to register all open popups to close them when the user triggers a new popup menu ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `.hide()` all the `.open` submenus by class

Comment: This is a job for an [event bus](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)