# How to use a directive in a component

Tags: vue.js, components, directive

I've been bashing my head against this for 9 hours now. How do I use a directive inside a component?

I'm trying to implement a click-outside event on my clickable components, following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170425/detect-click-outside-element?newreg=d1da80af94ef4b8387cd252ff5a0ba36). But my component is in a separate .vue file with template, etc, and I have been googling and throwing copy pasted code at it for hours and I just can't get it to work. It either can't find the imported file, or can't find the click-away function, or all sorts of crazy compile errors or runtime errors.

I'm still somewhat new to Vue, but what's the standard way of using a directive in a component? I thought it would be super simple, but I've got hundreds of tabs open and every single possible google link is purple, and nothing works. How are directives even possible if no ones using them with components?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Maybe this could help https://github.com/simplesmiler/vue-clickaway

Comment: Can you post some codes? Just the last code that you've used.

Comment: It should work fine, even within components. Instead of ranting here please paste a workable piece of code so this can at least be constructive.