# On click outside of some element in vue without packages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am wondering how can we hide all shown elements on click outside from those elements in vue:

```
<button @click="div1=true">Show div 1</button>
<div v-if="div1">DIV 1</div>

<button @click="div2=true">Show div 2</button>
<div v-if="div2">DIV 2</div>
```

How can I hide all divs besides div 1 if I click on div 1 or hide all divs on click on some random part of the page?
How does vuetify handle it?

Comment: Just [detect the click outside with a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42389266/5508690) and iterate through the open divs and set their display/hide property to false.

Comment: does not work for me even tho it works in fiddle I get `Cannot set property 'event' of undefined`

Comment: Did you look at the specific answer I linked? not the selected answer of the question as that was for vue 1.x.

Comment: @StevenB. yes i did

Answer (score 1):

Vue way is to use `this.$el` (DOM element of current component), you can change `this.$el` and use any other HTMLElement

```
<div class="modal" @click="handleClick">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And method should look like this

```
handleClick(e: Event): void {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLElement && !this.$el.contains(e.target)) {
    this.$emit("hide"); //fires only on click outside
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- It's easy to detect click outside of the element if you know how *event bubbling* works in DOM.
- Hiding other divs works perfectly well when you put state of every div into the components's state.

#### Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/0480m38mww?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue

---

Learn more about *Event Bubbling* here - https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 0):

I used this process so Home component would know that outside my Nav component has been clicked. It helps that I have my nav inside my Home Component.

My Home component template:

```
<div>
 <nav-bar ref="nav"></nav-bar>
  <div @click="useHideNavMethod()">
```

So I use `ref="nav"` to use methods from the Nav in my Home component. This means I can use the hideNav() method (which resides in Nav).
I have purposely put the nav outside of this div with the click method, so anywhere clicked other than Nav would initiate the useHideNavMethod() function.

In my Nav component template I have:

```
<nav id="nav">
```

which is referenced when I use `ref="nav"`.

So inside my hideNav() I have `this.styleNavLi.display = 'none';` so it would hide the nav bar.

So all I need to do to use that method in Home is to use:

```
useHideNavMethod() {
 this.$refs.nav.hideNav();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `div1 = !div1` for toggle view,
Or use `div1 = true` for one time only.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{ div1 }}
    <button @click="div1 = !div1">Show div 1</button>
    <div v-if="div1">DIV 1</div>

    {{ div2 }}
    <button @click="div2 = !div2">Show div 2</button>
    <div v-if="div2">DIV 2</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      div1: true, // set default value as you want
      div2: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```