# Is there a way to close a vue component by clicking outside of it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am looking for a way to close a component when there it a click outisde of the element.

I tried an `addEventListener`.
This closes the component but after being closed it will not open again.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e){

if (document.getElementById('shopcartpreview').contains(e.target)){
console.log("Clicked in Box");


} else{
console.log("Clicked outside Box");
$('#shopcartpreview').hide();
 }
 })
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
<template>
    <div id="shopcartpreview"  v-if="carthover">
        <div class="cartitem" v-for="item in cartitems">
            <div class="cartitempic"><img class="productImg" width="80px" height="80px" v-bind:src="'assets/products/' + item.image"></div>
            <div class="cartitemdetails">
                <div class="cartitemname">{{item.name}}</div>
                <div class="cartitemqty">1 X </div>
                <div class="cartitemprice">€{{item.unit_price}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="cartitemdelete">
                <img src="assets/images/icon-bin.png" width="15px" height="15px">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carttotal">
            <div class="carttotaltext">TOTAL:</div>
            <div class="carttotalprice">€2,860.00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="cartcheckouttbn">PROCEED TO CHECKOUT</div>
        <div class="viewcart">VIEW CART</div>



    </div>    
</template>
<script>
    module.exports = {
        data: function () {
                return{ 
                    cartitems: 0,
                    carthover: false,
                }
            },
            created(){
            EventBus.$on('addToCart', (payload) =>{
                this.cartitems = payload
            }),
            EventBus.$on('mouseover', (carthover) =>{
            this.carthover = carthover
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is your code to show the component?

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: How are you trying to show the component again in here?

Comment: I am not sure how (new to vue)

Comment: You can simply put a button and toggle the component with `v-show` directive

Comment: This can help : [click-outside directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36180348/9541423)

Answer (score 16):

I created a `div` element at the end of the component like that:

```
<div v-if="isPopup" class="outside" v-on:click="away()"></div>
```

Where `.outside` class is specified in CSS as follows:

```
.outside {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

And `away()` is a method in Vue instance as:

```
away() {
 this.isPopup = false;
}
```

Easy, works well.

Comment: Great answer! This is way simpler than setting up the directive. Thanks!

Comment: 'outside' class sometimes need z-index: -1

Comment: this doesn't work IF you have any buttons or other clickeable items in your view, as the click on this div will override their click. While adding z-index: -1 will take care of that issue, it will also result in you not being able to click this div everywhere, just on spaces where it doesn't 'overlap' with other divs.

Answer (score 4):

2020.11.10 Update

I find the previous solution I answered has so many errors, so I have to update it.

There are multiple solutions to close a component by clicking outside of it.

Firstly, there are some libraries which handle this problem, for example
[simplesmiler/vue-clickaway](https://github.com/simplesmiler/vue-clickaway/blob/master/index.js), the [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org) also use this script if you have read the source code.

Secondly, if you want to implement it manually, here is code:

```
onClickOutside ( event: Event ) {

    const path = event.path || (event.composedPath ? event.composedPath() : undefined)
    // check if the MouseClick occurs inside the component
    if (path && !path.includes(this.em) && !this.em.contains(event.target as HTMLElement)) {
      this.closeThisComponent() // whatever method which close your component
    }
  }
```

Then, you must bind this eventHandler `onClickOutside` to the `document.documentElement` after open your component and remove this eventHandler from `document.documentElement` after you close your component.

Please notice the timing and refers to the event loop of JavaScript, you must understand the difference between MicroTask and MacroTask.

For example, open the component

```
openThisComponent () {
    this.showThisCompoennt = true // whatever codes which open your component

    // You can also use Vue.$nextTick or setTimeout
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', this.onClickOutside, false)
    })

  }
```

```
closeThisComponent () {
    this.showComponent = false // whatever codes which close your component
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('click', this.onClickOutside, false)
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Demo Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bq8m4fhe/

Create a clickoutside directive ...  [Detect click outside element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170425/detect-click-outside-element/36180348)

```
module.exports = {
    data: function() {
        return {
            cartitems: 0,
            carthover: false
        };
    },
    directives: {
        clickoutside: {
            bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
                el.clickOutsideEvent = function(event) {
                    // here I check that click was outside the el and his childrens
                    if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
                        // and if it did, call method provided in attribute value
                        vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
                    }
                };
                document.body.addEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
                document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", el.clickOutsideEvent);
            },
            unbind: function(el) {
                document.body.removeEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
                document.body.removeEventListener("touchstart", el.clickOutsideEvent);
            },
            stopProp(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        EventBus.$on("addToCart", payload => {
            this.cartitems = payload;
        }),
        EventBus.$on("mouseover", carthover => {
            this.carthover = carthover;
        });
    }
};
```

Use that directive like this.

```
<div id="shopcartpreview"  v-if="carthover" v-clickoutside="SHOPPING_CART_HIDE_FUNCTION">
```