# Buefy - Close notification on click anywhere

Tags: vue.js, bulma, buefy

I'm wondering if it is possible to modifiy the [notification system of buefy](https://buefy.org/documentation/notification/) so that it closes itself when I click **anywhere on the notification**, not just on the x-cross generated by `closable: true`.
I have been looking for solutions to change the default behavior of buefy elements, but I haven't found anything coming close (no pun intended).
Any help would be very much appreciated.

**edit**: I want to close the notification by clicking on it, not outside of it. But I don't know how to attach the onClick behaviour to the buefy element as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to catch click anywhere on the page and then:

```
isActive = !isActive
```

The question how to catch click outside the element is answered here:
[Detect click outside element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170425/detect-click-outside-element)
But watch out! Preferred answer is not working in Vue.js 2. You can try to use this package: https://github.com/MuTsunTsai/vue-on-clickout

Comment: Glad that you mentioned the package I created; however, if one simply needs to detect "click anywhere" event, one really should just add an event handler on the document itself, not by adding both "click" and "clickout" events on the same element and perform the same task in them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `v-clickaway` to detect click outside your element:

[Vue-clickaway](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-clickaway)

and then set your flag to true