# How to fix this error: "vnode.context[binding.expression]"?

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I'm building an app using VueJS. I have a component and I want to know when I click outside of it. I searched for a solution and I find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170425/detect-click-outside-element#answer-42389266) on Stack Overflow, but I get this error when I implemented the answer:

```
TypeError: vnode.context[binding.expression] is not a function
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I used to have this problem. The fix is to bind the custom directive to a function expression, not a function call.

e.g.

```
<div v-custom-directive="someMethod" ></div> // GOOD

<div v-custom-directive="someMethod(argument1, argument2)" // BAD

<div v-custom-directive="() => someMethod(argument1, argument2)" // ALSO BAD?

<div v-custom-directive="e => someMethod(argument1, argument2)" // GOOD
```

Why?

`binding.expression` is a string representation of the code that should execute when the directive is triggered, which should be a function. This is - cutting some corners here - parsed with `vnode.context` and then called with `(event)`. So, `someMethod(argument1, argument2)` will give an error, unless someMethod itself returns a function, because in reality you're calling `someMethod(argument1, argument2)(event)`. If you wrap it in an arrow function that accepts the event as an argument, you can call a function with your desired arguments.

Answer (score 1):

For my part, it was because I had conflict with the directive name, I renamed it and bind it with my "custom-click-outside" and it worked.