# How can I access binding.expression in Vue 3?

Tags: binding, expression, vuejs3, custom-directive

I am not able to find binding.expression in Vue 3 from my custom directive's events.
Has it been replaced by something else?

I need to access the raw expression to process it rather than the evaluated expression value.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrating "detect click outside" custom directive from Vue 2 to Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63869859/migrating-detect-click-outside-custom-directive-from-vue-2-to-vue-3)

Comment: Hi Michal. No, unfortunately I need to access the raw expression passed to the directive. Do you know how in Vue 3?

Comment: I'm, pretty sure it was removed for some reason but I was not able to find any explanation why. Just [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/3107) talking about it should be documented...