# How can i close my modal when i click outside of my modal?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I am trying to use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/click-outside-vue3 for close when i will click outside of the modal?

**i made this code:**

```
<div
    v-if="dialogFoundation"
    v-click-outside="close"
  >

 import vClickOutside from 'click-outside-vue3'
 directives: {
  clickOutside: vClickOutside.directive
},
setup() {

  const close = () => {
        console.log(4343)
  }
}
```

but its not working, i want to close the modal

also i setup the main.js

```
import vClickOutside from "click-outside-vue3"
...
createApp(App)
  .use(vClickOutside)
```

Comment: I did have work around this, check this one [Detect click outside element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170425/detect-click-outside-element)

Comment: @Naren i want to use that library please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you set the directive as it's found in the documentation ?

````
directives: {
      clickOutside: vClickOutside.directive
    },

```
````

Comment: yep, also i did that