# Detect click outside div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to detect a click inside or outside a div area. The tricky part is that the div will contain other elements and if one of the elements inside the div is clicked, it should be considered a click inside, the same way if an element from outside the div is clicked, it should be considered an outside click.

I've been researching a lot but all I could find were examples in jquery and I need pure javascript.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element?rq=1 and then just change the jquery click bindings for javascript click bindings.

Comment: What examples did you find that were using jQuery? Perhaps you should just try to "translate" those to vanilla JS and ask about that if you don't know how.

Comment: you can call the function to be called from inline onclick function of the HTML element `<div onclick="yourFunction()"> </div>`

Answer (score 247, accepted):

It depends on the individual use case but it sounds like in this example there are likely to be other nested elements inside the main div e.g. more divs, lists etc.  Using [Node.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) would be a useful way to check whether the target element is within the div that is being checked.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e){   
  if (document.getElementById('clickbox').contains(e.target)){
    // Clicked in box
  } else{
    // Clicked outside the box
  }
});
```

An example that has a nested list inside is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kym2rvyL/1/).

Comment: `if (!document.getElementById('clickbox').contains(e.target)){ // Clicked outside box }` is perhaps a working and shorter solution?

Comment: This is working but not perfectly. It is not working when clicking an inside 'absolute' positioned element. Can we handle that case?

Comment: instead of using `window.addEventListener` use `document.addEventListener` it gonna do the work , especially in js frameworks (vue,react and angular)

Answer (score 7):

You can check if the clicked Element is the div you want to check or not:

```
document.getElementById('outer-container').onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target != document.getElementById('content-area')) {
      console.log('You clicked outside');
  } else {
      console.log('You clicked inside');
  }
}
```

Referring to [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893144/javascript-detect-click-event-outside-of-div).

Comment: For what it's worth - you're far better off adding the listener using `.addEventListener`- you can remove it, but more importantly, you can set a number of functions to fire when the event is received. You also gain meaningful access to the `this` keyword inside the function that handles the event, `this` then resolves to the element itself - nice to know which element triggered the event, for instance.You also get the event object, which triggered the handler in the first place. In any case, the method of attaching the event handlers is considerably more powerful. :)

Answer (score 4):

you can apply if check for that inside your click event

```
if(event.target.parentElement.id == 'yourID')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  closePopover () {
var windowBody = window
var popover = document.getElementById('popover-wrapper') as HTMLDivElement; 
windowBody?.addEventListener('click', function(event){ 
    if(popover === event.target) {
      console.log("clicked on the div")
    }
    if(popover !== event.target) {
      console.log("clicked outside the div")
    }
})
```

}
}

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 6 and IONIC 3, I do same as here:

```
import {Component} from 'angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ion-content padding (click)="onClick($event)">
      <div id="warning-container">
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  onClick(event) {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    if (document.getElementById('warning-container').contains(target)){
      // Clicked in box
    } else{
      // Clicked outside the box
    }
  }
}
```

This working fine on web/android/ios.
It might be helpful for someone, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In React you can use `useClickOutside` hook from [react-cool-onclickoutside](https://github.com/wellyshen/react-cool-onclickoutside).

Demo from Github:

```
import { useClickOutside } from 'use-events';

const Example = () => {
  const ref1 = React.useRef(null);
  const ref2 = React.useRef(null);
  const [isActive] = useClickOutside([ref1, ref2], event => console.log(event));

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={ref1} style={{ border: '1px dotted black' }}>
        You are {isActive ? 'clicking' : 'not clicking'} outside of this div
      </div>
      <br />
      <div ref={ref2} style={{ border: '1px dotted black' }}>
        You are {isActive ? 'clicking' : 'not clicking'} outside of this div
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Live demo](https://sandiiarov.github.io/use-events/#/docs-use-click-outside)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution it uses pure javascript and it solves your problem. I added css just for better overview... but it is not needed.

```js
document.getElementById('outer-div').addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('clicked outer div...');
});

document.getElementById('inner-div').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation()
  alert('clicked inner div...');
});
```

```css
#outer-div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}

#inner-div{
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
  <div id="inner-div">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a hack for this that's working well for me and that might help others.

When I pop up my dialog DIV, I simultaneously display another transparent DIV just behind it, covering the whole screen.

This invisible background DIV closes the dialog DIV onClick.

This is pretty straightforward, so I'm not going to bother with the code here. LMK in the comments if you want to see it and I'll add it in.

HTH!

Comment: it might be straightforward for experts. But so far of all the solutions posted this might be what I need as I have a div table that displays an info when clicked, and don't think I'm confident with the addEventListeners. Yours might be a good way for me. Curious how would I create an invisible background DIV around the displayedDiv

Comment: Something like this <div><div>content</div></div>. HTH!

Comment: Completely unhelpful IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I recently needed a simple vanilla JS solution which solves for:

- Ignoring specific selectors including whether a parent contains one of these selectors
- Ignoring specific DOM nodes

This solution has worked quite well in my app.

```
const isClickedOutsideElement = ({ clickEvent, elToCheckOutside, ignoreElems = [], ignoreSelectors = [] }) => {
    const clickedEl = clickEvent.srcElement;
    const didClickOnIgnoredEl = ignoreElems.filter(el => el).some(element => element.contains(clickedEl) || element.isEqualNode(clickedEl));
    const didClickOnIgnoredSelector = ignoreSelectors.length ? ignoreSelectors.map(selector => clickedEl.closest(selector)).reduce((curr, accumulator) => curr && accumulator, true) : false;

    if (
      isDOMElement(elToCheckOutside) &&
      !elToCheckOutside.contains(clickedEl) &&
      !didClickOnIgnoredEl &&
      !didClickOnIgnoredSelector
    ){
      return true;
    }

    return false;
}

  const isDOMElement = (element) => {
    return element instanceof Element || element instanceof HTMLDocument;  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of these solutions are with the assumption you only have one popover/menu/modal at a time. If you have several items, each with its own menu, they won't work without significant modification. My solution is as follows:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // Check if click done inside popover
  const container = event.target.closest('.popover');

  // Check if popover open/close button was clicked
  const buttonTarget = event.target.dataset.target;

  // Ensure all popovers are closed if not requested or clicked inside
  for (let popover of document.getElementsByClassName('popover')) {
    if (popover.id === buttonTarget && popover.style.display !== `block`) {
      popover.style.display = `block`;
    } else if (!container) {
      popover.style.display = `none`;
    }
  }
}, false);
```

Note that the above requires a `data-target` attribute on the button/input/link set to the modal/popover's id, and a class of popover on all modal/popover items. You can adjust as necessary. You can also dispense with the container check if you want the menu to close as soon as any option has been clicked.

Comment: Thank you; too many people post shallow solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="window.dialog.showModal()">Open dialog</button>

<dialog id="dialog" style="padding: 0; border: 0;">
  <form method="dialog">
    <div>Hello from dialog element. You can close me by clicking outside or Close button</div>
    <button>Close</button>
  </form>
</dialog>    

function onClick(event) {
      if (event.target === dialog) {
        dialog.close();
      }
    }
    
    const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");
    dialog.addEventListener("click", onClick);
    dialog.showModal();
```

I found the code very simple.

Font: https://codepen.io/dvdvdmt/pen/BaavWbp