# how to trigger a click event by specifying coordinate position(x,y) in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a bootstrap modal that has a form. I need to be able to click outside the modal so that the modal closes when the form is submitted. how can i achieve this in react, thanks

EDIT:

```
bootstrap_modal
   form_inside_bootstrap_modal
      submit_button_inside_form
   </ form_inside_bootstrap_modal>
</ bootstrap_modal>
```

I want to be able to close the bootstrap modal when submit_button_inside_form is clicked

SOLUTION:

```
document.elementFromPoint(x,y).click()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36695438/detect-click-outside-div-using-javascript

Comment: Your question is unclear, Could you please elaborate more what you exactly want.

Comment: please check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simulating a click at a position: x,y coordinates with javascript which can be achieved using this

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `eventListener` on `click` in `componentDidMount`.

like this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if (document.getElementById("modalWindow").contains(e.target)) {
        alert("clicked inside");
      } else {
        alert("clicked outside");
      }
    });
    return () => window.removeEventListener("click");
  }, []);
```

see the example i wrote [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-shadow-fmfzb).

Comment: thank you, but my i have to simulate a click event in the window,(somewhere outside the modal) when a button inside the modal is clicked

Comment: @kritiz and the example didn't do that? hmmm. It seems it is doing that.

Comment: the example shows me where I clicked , (outside or inside) but I need to make a click event outside the modal  when I click a button inside the  modal

Comment: Do you mean you need to run a function which in upper level, when click on the button?