# Play an audio file when click is inside image and a different audio file when click is outside image

Tags: javascript, html, image, audio, onclick

I am learning HTML-CSS-JS by doing some little exercises of my own. I have created a little code that plays an mp3 audio when I click on an image:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Image audio exercise</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function play(){
         var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
         audio.play();
      }
    </script>
    <img src="img.gif" onclick="play()">
    <audio id="audio" src="sound.mp3" ></audio>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I would like to be able to play a different audio file when the click is outside the image. Is there a simple way to do it? Maybe an if-else statement?

Comment: Check this issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893144/javascript-detect-click-event-outside-of-div) maybe can help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
if (e.target != document.getElementById('clickMe')) {
    document.getElementById('audio').play();
}else {
    document.getElementById('audio2').play();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this. Just a simple check to see if you clicked on the image or the document.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image audio exercise</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <img id="theImage" src="img.gif">
    <audio id="audio" src="sound.mp3" ></audio>

    <script>
      var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
      var img = document.getElementById("theImage");

      document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
         if( e.target === img ){
           audio.src = "sound.mp3";
           audio.play();
         }
         else{
           audio.src = "sound2.mp3";
           audio.play();
         }
      },false);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```